# Unreal Engine 4 -- Typecasting

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am currently developing my first classes in Unreal Engine 4.  Coming from using UScript extensively, I'm getting a little bit confused by how typecasting works in pure C++.  More specifically, class/object casting.

I am currently putting together a switch statement in MyCustomGameMode which calls upon MyCustomPlayerController for MyCustomPlayerControllerVariable.

The function in question that I am overriding is this one: `virtual UClass* GetDefaultPawnClassForController(AController* InController);`

Currently I'm trying to call the variable with the following line of code, which I know is incorrect, but I'm not sure why:

```
Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController).MyCustomPlayerControllerVariable
```

I am interested in casting the "InController" to MyCustomPlayerController but `Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController)` doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible migration to gamedev.stackexchange?

Comment: You are correctly casting it, can you show us the full implementation of this function? And why you don't think it works? Also, does MyCustomPlayerController inherit from AController?

Answer (score 3):

The cast will return a pointer to your player controller, so you'd need to use -> to dereference it.

```
const MyCustomPlayerController* MyController = Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController);
check(MyCustomPlayerController);  // asserts that the cast succeeded
const float MyVariable = MyCustomPlayerController->ControllerVariable;
```

`

Answer (score 3):

When you cast, It always returns a pointer. So make sure you check if the cast is successful before you access variables from a pointer.

```
auto MyPC = Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController);
if(MyPC)
{
    MyPC->MyVariable;
}
```